# Apache2 restore files

Tags: 10.10, apache2

How to restore all apache2 files, i mean i want to set the files to be like the default ones for apache2 . How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can open a terminal and enter:

```
sudo aptitude reinstall apache2
```

This should bring  back removed files and if files have changed you'll be asked what to do with them.